# Почему кнопка фильтра по цене не работает?

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на `<th> Price <th>` товары должны сортироваться по цене, но этого не происходит. Помогите мне исправить это

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }

    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
        const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
        });
        return sorted;
    }
}
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("anything 4", 4, 1000));

const table = document.getElementById("shop");
const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");
for (let i = 0; i < shop.products.length; i++) {
    //create table
    table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${shop.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${shop.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${shop.products[i].count}</td></tr>`;
}
//filter products by price
priceFilter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    shop.products.price.sortProductsByPrice(Product.Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
}, false);
```

```html
    <table id="shop">
        <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th id="filter">Price:</th>
            <th>Count:</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная ошибка в том, что объекты вы отсортировали, а пересоздать таблицу забыли

Ну и в этой строке

```
shop.products.price.sortProductsByPrice(Product.Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

неправильно почти все.

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
  constructor(name, count, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
Product.SORT_ORDER_DESC = -1;
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
  constructor(products) {
    this.products = [];
  }

  //method for adding a product
  addProduct(newProduct) {
    this.products.push(newProduct);
  }

  //method for sorting the product at its price
  sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
    const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
    });
    return sorted;
  }

  show() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
    for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const e = rows.item(i);
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    }
    const table = document.getElementById("shop");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      //create table
      table.innerHTML += `<tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr>`;
    }
  }
}
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("anything 4", 4, 1000));

shop.show();
const priceFilter = document.getElementById("filter");
//filter products by price
priceFilter.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  shop.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
  shop.show();
}, false);
```

```html
<table id="shop">
  <caption>Products that are available in the store</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <th id="filter">Price:</th>
    <th>Count:</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```